# Bump function: $K\subset U$, $f\equiv 1$ on $K$, $supp(f)=cl(U)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $V\subset\subset U\subset\subset\mathbb{R}^n$  be an open sets and $K=cl(V)$. How to prove that there is  a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ of class $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $$0\le f(x)\le 1\;,\;\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n$$ $$f(x)=1\;,\;\forall x\in K$$ $$supp(f)=cl(U)$$ $$0<f(x)<1\;,\;\forall x\in U-K$$

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the double $\subset$ supposed to be $\subseteq$ or what does it mean?

Comment: Relatively compact $cl(V)\subset U$ and $cl(V)$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint/set up:** Let $\varphi \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be the standard mollifier, which is defined by 
$$\varphi(x) =\begin{cases}0 & |x|\ge 1,\\ Ce^{-\frac{1}{1-|x|^2}} & |x|<1,\end{cases}$$ where $C$ is a constant such that $\|\varphi\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)} = 1$. Let $\{\varphi_{\epsilon}\}$ be the associated family of mollifiers defined by $\varphi_{\epsilon}(x) := \epsilon^{-n}\varphi(x/\epsilon)$. By construction, $\varphi_{\epsilon}$ satisfies the following properties:

- $\varphi_{\epsilon} \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$
- $\varphi_{\epsilon} \ge 0$
- $ \text{supp}(\varphi_{\epsilon}) = \overline{B(0,\epsilon)}$
- $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\varphi_{\epsilon}(x)\, dx = 1$.

Now set $0 < d = \text{dist}(\partial V,U)$ and let $K_{d/2} : = \{x \in U : \text{dist}(x,K) < \frac d2\}$. Then, if $\chi$ is the characteristic function of $K_{d/2}$, $$f := \varphi_{d/2} * \chi$$ should do the trick. I won't take from you the pleasure of checking all the details!

---

In case you are not familiar with mollifiers or the smoothening property of the convolution I'd recommend reading the Wikipedia page on [mollifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#Definition). If you have access to it, [Analysis by Lieb and Loss](https://books.google.com/books/about/Analysis.html?id=Eb_7oRorXJgC) does a great job covering the material you seem to be interested in.