# Define a particular function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, special-functions

Does anybody know how you can define a function $\eta \in C_c^1(B_R(0))$ such that
$\eta = 1$ on $B_{\frac{R}{2}}(0)$ cause I need such a function in a particular proof, so I would really like to know if something like this is possible. (I don't know how you get the transitions smooth). Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: take a look at my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432753/bump-function-k-subset-u-f-equiv-1-on-k-suppf-clu/1432797#1432797 (you are asking for something easier to construct, but since among the tags you included pde, you'll probably find it satisfactory and adequate to your level)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function:

$$ f(x) = 1-\exp\left(-\cot^2(\pi x)\right),\qquad f(0)=1,\;f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=f\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)=0. $$
over $I=\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]$.

We have $f\in C^{\infty}(I)$ and all the derivatives of $f$ at $x=0$ vanish, hence the function defined by:

$$ g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 1 &\text{if}& -\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq\frac{1}{2},\\f\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)&\text{if}&\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq 1,\\f\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)&\text{if}&-1\leq x\leq -\frac{1}{2}\end{array}\right.\tag{2}$$
over $[-1,1]$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function that equals one over $\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]$.

By considering $g\!\left(\frac{\|x\|}{R}\right)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{\|x\|\leq R}\,$  you get your function.

See also the Wikipedia entry about [mollifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier).

Comment: thank you very much for this fast clarification

Comment: by the way, I think you want to have  a slightly faster decay, cause your function has support $\overline{B_R(0)},$ but I was looking for a function whose support is compactly contained in $B_R(0).$

Comment: @user167575: you just have to adjust the scaling ratio and the length of the interval over which $g(x)$ equals one to achieve that, since the derivatives of $f(x)$ at the endpoints of $I$ also vanish. To have a faster decay, you may also replace the $2$ in $\exp\left(-\cot^{\color{red}{2}}(\pi x)\right)$ with a bigger even number.